# LDAP structure for "domain users" group

Tags: ldap-query

Can anyone help me in configuring LDAP for "domain users" built-in group ??

I have configured a service account which is authenticating successfully and I am in need of configuring authorization profile for "domain users" for the same service account but I don't know how to find the Bind DN, group search base, group filter & group return attribute for "domain users", kindly help me in it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your LDAP OpenLDAP or AD? Is this for a specific application/programming language?

Comment: Hi ChadSikorra,

Thanks for your reply. It's an AD and I found a solution for it by making changes in the below fields,

User return attribute =primaryGroupID & 
Group Search filter = (objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(primaryGroupID={primaryGroupID})

Cheers !!